# GA GEO Chart cities labeled incorrectly

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-api, google-visualization, google-analytics-api

I have a page that connects to a google analytics account. On the page I have a GEO chart focused on the state of Florida.

When I hover over the markers on the map, about half of the markers appear to be correct. The other half are labeled with city names that dont match their marker on the map. Like markers in the middle of the state being labeled as a city in Brazil For examples see the screenshots below.

Here's my code that sets up the GEO Charts. Any idea what Im doing wrong?

Also here is a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/hoqupapana/2/edit?html,css,js)

```
(function(w,d,s,g,js,fjs){
  g=w.gapi||(w.gapi={});g.analytics={q:[],ready:function(cb){this.q.push(cb);}};
  js=d.createElement(s);fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  js.src='https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js';
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);js.onload=function(){g.load('analytics');};
}(window,document,'script'));




gapi.analytics.ready(function() {

  var CLIENT_ID = '663097249213-ankiu39ud1m7imaa4r5h5mtt4bnpp9b5.apps.googleusercontent.com';

  gapi.analytics.auth.authorize({
    container: 'auth-button',
    clientid: CLIENT_ID,
  });

  var viewSelector = new gapi.analytics.ViewSelector({
   container: 'view-selector'
  });

  var stateMap = new gapi.analytics.googleCharts.DataChart({
    query: {
      'dimensions': 'ga:city',
      'metrics': 'ga:sessions',
      'start-date': '14daysAgo',
      'end-date': 'yesterday',
    },
    chart: {
      type: 'GEO',
      container: 'state',
      options: {
        region: 'US-FL', 
        resolution: 'metros',
        displayMode: 'markers',
        width:'100%',
        height:'100%',
        keepAspectRatio:true
      }
    }
  });



  gapi.analytics.auth.on('success', function(response) {
    viewSelector.execute();
    $('#auth-button').hide();
  });



  viewSelector.on('change', function(ids) {
    var newIds = {
      query: {
        ids: ids
      }
    };
    stateMap.set(newIds).execute();
  });
});
```

Here are the request headers:

```
Remote Address:74.125.137.95:443
Request URL:https://content.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?start-date=7daysAgo&end-date=yesterday&dimensions=ga%3AuserType&metrics=ga%3Asessions&sort=-ga%3Asessions&max-results=9&ids=ga%3A91097884&output=dataTable&embedApiVersion=v1
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headers
:host:content.googleapis.com
:method:GET
:path:/analytics/v3/data/ga?start-date=7daysAgo&end-date=yesterday&dimensions=ga%3AuserType&metrics=ga%3Asessions&sort=-ga%3Asessions&max-results=9&ids=ga%3A91097884&output=dataTable&embedApiVersion=v1
:scheme:https
:version:HTTP/1.1
accept:*/*
accept-encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
accept-language:en-US,en;q=0.8
authorization:Bearer ya29.qgAhgT4Oq1u6e_cfcv1qP2ieP_QUbPM0WozLPpagwZ_9rmXM8G0s0uDK
cache-control:no-cache
pragma:no-cache
referer:https://content.googleapis.com/static/proxy.html?jsh=m%3B%2F_%2Fscs%2Fapps-static%2F_%2Fjs%2Fk%3Doz.gapi.en.FnxxMUT2ulE.O%2Fm%3D__features__%2Fam%3DAQ%2Frt%3Dj%2Fd%3D1%2Ft%3Dzcms%2Frs%3DAGLTcCMEC-DWdYC4P42L_5byzwhSZYF3Cg
user-agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/38.0.2125.104 Safari/537.36
x-client-data:CJe2yQEIprbJAQiptskBCMG2yQEI8IjKAQiPlMoBCN6WygE=
x-clientdetails:appVersion=5.0%20(Macintosh%3B%20Intel%20Mac%20OS%20X%2010_10_0)%20AppleWebKit%2F537.36%20(KHTML%2C%20like%20Gecko)%20Chrome%2F38.0.2125.104%20Safari%2F537.36&platform=MacIntel&userAgent=Mozilla%2F5.0%20(Macintosh%3B%20Intel%20Mac%20OS%20X%2010_10_0)%20AppleWebKit%2F537.36%20(KHTML%2C%20like%20Gecko)%20Chrome%2F38.0.2125.104%20Safari%2F537.36
x-goog-encode-response-if-executable:base64
x-javascript-user-agent:google-api-javascript-client/1.1.0-beta
x-origin:http://affordable-glass.com
x-referer:http://affordable-glass.com
Query String Parametersview sourceview URL encoded
start-date:7daysAgo
end-date:yesterday
dimensions:ga:userType
metrics:ga:sessions
sort:-ga:sessions
max-results:9
ids:ga:91097884
output:dataTable
embedApiVersion:v1
Response Headers
alternate-protocol:443:quic,p=0.01
cache-control:private, max-age=0, must-revalidate, no-transform
content-encoding:gzip
content-length:555
content-type:application/json; charset=UTF-8
date:Sun, 26 Oct 2014 00:35:09 GMT
etag:"C7PuqpcNYAngGhjHeeJxl43WaQM/65Qv4TMpW0C9gHm-VUHXAtDeU9g"
expires:Sun, 26 Oct 2014 00:35:09 GMT
server:GSE
status:200 OK
vary:Referer
vary:X-Origin
vary:Origin
version:HTTP/1.1
x-content-type-options:nosniff
x-frame-options:SAMEORIGIN
x-xss-protection:1; mode=block
```

Here is the data that gets returned by Google:

```js
{
  "kind": "analytics#gaData",
  "id": "https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids=ga:91097884&dimensions=ga:city&metrics=ga:sessions&start-date=14daysAgo&end-date=yesterday",
  "query": {
    "start-date": "14daysAgo",
    "end-date": "yesterday",
    "ids": "ga:91097884",
    "dimensions": "ga:city",
    "metrics": ["ga:sessions"],
    "start-index": 1,
    "max-results": 1000
  },
  "itemsPerPage": 1000,
  "totalResults": 47,
  "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids=ga:91097884&dimensions=ga:city&metrics=ga:sessions&start-date=14daysAgo&end-date=yesterday",
  "profileInfo": {
    "profileId": "91097884",
    "accountId": "54755159",
    "webPropertyId": "UA-54755159-1",
    "internalWebPropertyId": "87741876",
    "profileName": "All Web Site Data",
    "tableId": "ga:91097884"
  },
  "containsSampledData": false,
  "columnHeaders": [{
    "name": "ga:city",
    "columnType": "DIMENSION",
    "dataType": "STRING"
  }, {
    "name": "ga:sessions",
    "columnType": "METRIC",
    "dataType": "INTEGER"
  }],
  "totalsForAllResults": {
    "ga:sessions": "75"
  },
  "dataTable": {
    "cols": [{
      "id": "ga:city",
      "label": "ga:city",
      "type": "string"
    }, {
      "id": "ga:sessions",
      "label": "ga:sessions",
      "type": "number"
    }],
    "rows": [{
      "c": [{
        "v": "(not set)"
      }, {
        "v": "3"
      }]
    }, {
      "c": [{
        "v": "Ashburn"
      }, {
        "v": "1"
      }]
    }, {
      "c": [{
        "v": "Atlanta"
      }, {
        "v": "4"
      }]
    }, {
      "c": [{
        "v": "Bari"
      }, {
        "v": "1"
      }]
    }, {
      "c": [{
        "v": "Belo Horizonte"
      }, {
        "v": "1"
      }]
    }, {
      "c": [{
        "v": "Biloxi"
      }, {
        "v": "1"
      }]
    }, {
      "c": [{
        "v": "Birmingham"
      }, {
        "v": "1"
      }]
    }, {
      "c": [{
        "v": "Bradenton"
      }, {
        "v": "2"
      }]
    }, {
      "c": [{
        "v": "Chandler"
      }, {
        "v": "2"
      }]
    }, {
      "c": [{
        "v": "Columbus"
      }, {
        "v": "1"
      }]
    }, {
      "c": [{
        "v": "Cordoba"
      }, {
        "v": "1"
      }]
    }, {
      "c": [{
        "v": "Dallas"
      }, {
        "v": "1"
      }]
    }, {
      "c": [{
        "v": "Eastpoint"
      }, {
        "v": "1"
      }]
    }, {
      "c": [{
        "v": "Erlanger"
      }, {
        "v": "1"
      }]
    }, {
      "c": [{
        "v": "Fort Bragg"
      }, {
        "v": "1"
      }]
    }, {
      "c": [{
        "v": "Foz do Iguacu"
      }, {
        "v": "1"
      }]
    }, {
      "c": [{
        "v": "Fresno"
      }, {
        "v": "1"
      }]
    }, {
      "c": [{
        "v": "Funchal"
      }, {
        "v": "1"
      }]
    }, {
      "c": [{
        "v": "Houston"
      }, {
        "v": "1"
      }]
    }, {
      "c": [{
        "v": "Jacksonville"
      }, {
        "v": "1"
      }]
    }, {
      "c": [{
        "v": "Lake Oswego"
      }, {
        "v": "1"
      }]
    }, {
      "c": [{
        "v": "Lake Worth"
      }, {
        "v": "2"
      }]
    }, {
      "c": [{
        "v": "Londrina"
      }, {
        "v": "2"
      }]
    }, {
      "c": [{
        "v": "Lynn Haven"
      }, {
        "v": "2"
      }]
    }, {
      "c": [{
        "v": "Mar del Plata"
      }, {
        "v": "1"
      }]
    }, {
      "c": [{
        "v": "Marianna"
      }, {
        "v": "2"
      }]
    }, {
      "c": [{
        "v": "Middletown"
      }, {
        "v": "2"
      }]
    }, {
      "c": [{
        "v": "Miramar Beach"
      }, {
        "v": "1"
      }]
    }, {
      "c": [{
        "v": "Montreal"
      }, {
        "v": "1"
      }]
    }, {
      "c": [{
        "v": "Navarre"
      }, {
        "v": "1"
      }]
    }, {
      "c": [{
        "v": "Panama City"
      }, {
        "v": "9"
      }]
    }, {
      "c": [{
        "v": "Panama City Beach"
      }, {
        "v": "7"
      }]
    }, {
      "c": [{
        "v": "Pecan Grove"
      }, {
        "v": "1"
      }]
    }, {
      "c": [{
        "v": "Porto Alegre"
      }, {
        "v": "1"
      }]
    }, {
      "c": [{
        "v": "Providence"
      }, {
        "v": "1"
      }]
    }, {
      "c": [{
        "v": "Rio de Janeiro"
      }, {
        "v": "1"
      }]
    }, {
      "c": [{
        "v": "Sabadell"
      }, {
        "v": "1"
      }]
    }, {
      "c": [{
        "v": "Sao Paulo"
      }, {
        "v": "3"
      }]
    }, {
      "c": [{
        "v": "Seria"
      }, {
        "v": "1"
      }]
    }, {
      "c": [{
        "v": "Surrey"
      }, {
        "v": "1"
      }]
    }, {
      "c": [{
        "v": "Tallahassee"
      }, {
        "v": "1"
      }]
    }, {
      "c": [{
        "v": "Tampa"
      }, {
        "v": "1"
      }]
    }, {
      "c": [{
        "v": "The Woodlands"
      }, {
        "v": "1"
      }]
    }, {
      "c": [{
        "v": "Toronto"
      }, {
        "v": "1"
      }]
    }, {
      "c": [{
        "v": "Virginia Beach"
      }, {
        "v": "1"
      }]
    }, {
      "c": [{
        "v": "Wellington"
      }, {
        "v": "1"
      }]
    }, {
      "c": [{
        "v": "Wyndham"
      }, {
        "v": "1"
      }]
    }]
  }
}
```

[image]
[image]

It does the same if I try it with a US map:
[image]

Comment: show the data you are posting

Comment: @DanielA.White added the returned data above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have been working with the GEO chart for the EMBED api and had the exact same issues. It seems to me that the GEO chart is pretty feature limited, and the region you set has no bearing on what data it shows, but instead, only zooms the map to the appropriate viewing area. I added a filter to my query, I think this will work for you...

```
"query": {
    "start-date": "14daysAgo",
    "end-date": "yesterday",
    "ids": "ga:91097884",
    "dimensions": "ga:city",
    "metrics": ["ga:sessions"],
    "start-index": 1,
    "max-results": 1000,
    "filters": "ga:region==Florida"
 },
```

Note the last line with the filter, I know this may not be ideal, but it is the only way I could get the Embed GEO chart to work properly.

Comment: Ronnie, you are a lifesaver! This was not at all clear in any of the documentation I went through. Thank you!