# Google Data Studio, Geo Chart, some data coming through as (not set)

Tags: looker-studio

I'm using a Geo Chart in Google Data Studio.  It is only set at the state level, so when viewing the map, you see the United States and each of the individual states on it.  If you do NOT apply a filter or segment to it, **some** of the state data comes through correctly, but on several states, it does not.  In specific, various international cities appear on hover rather than U.S. state data.  For example, you can see here that hovering over Texas brings up Victoria.

[image: No filter - City data]

I found this post in stack overflow [GA GEO Chart cities labeled incorrectly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26520818/ga-geo-chart-cities-labeled-incorrectly).  It essentially suggests creating a filter. It is *almost* working correctly. I have tried to apply a filter, a segment, and both to the data. The strange city data goes away, replaced by the correct state data, but I have one state where the data comes through as (not set) rather than as the state. In specific, hovering over WI brings up (not set) data.  It is the only state where I have a problem.

[image: States with filter]

If anyone has any suggestions, would love to hear it.  Thanks!

Also, when you change the chart to a table, all of the data appears correctly, so WI and TX both have their data correct from the source.

Answer (score 0):

I not only have a segment/filter for the United States, I added a filter to exclude all (not set)'s.  The state data now comes up fine!